# Sorting array of string having year and month

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array like below

```
var testArr = ["2009-feb", "2009-jan", "2010-mar", "2010-jan", "2011-jul", "2011-sep", "2011-jan", "2012-jan", "2012-dec", "2012-feb", "2013-may", "2013-jul", "2013-jun", "2014-jan", "2014-dec", "2014-may", "2015-may", "2015-jan", "2015-jun", "2016-jan", "2016-dec"];
```

I need to sort them I did following

```
var sortOrder="asc";
testArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (sortOrder == "asc") {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
    else {
        return b.localeCompare(a);
    }
});
```

The out put is

```
["2009-feb","2009-jan","2010-jan","2010-mar","2011-jan","2011-jul","2011-sep","2012-dec","2012-feb","2012-jan","2013-jul","2013-jun","2013-may","2014-dec","2014-jan","2014-may","2015-jan","2015-jun","2015-may","2016-dec","2016-jan"]
```

which is wrong.

Comment: And what went wrong ?

Comment: I do not see a specific question.

Comment: He wants to sort by date, not in alphabet order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a function which separates the date string and returns an array with the year and a month number. The month is taken from an object with month names as hashes.

```js
function yearMonth(a, b) {
    function getDate(f) {
        var d = f.split('-');
        d[1] = {
            jan: 1, feb: 2, mar: 3, apr: 4, may: 5, jun: 6, jul: 7, aug: 8, sep: 9, oct: 10, nov: 11, dec: 12
        }[d[1].substring(0, 3).toLowerCase()] || 0;
        return d;
    }

    var aa = getDate(a),
        bb = getDate(b);

    return aa[0] - bb[0] || aa[1] - bb[1];
}

var testArr = ["2009-feb", "2009-jan", "2010-mar", "2010-jan", "2011-jul", "2011-sep", "2011-jan", "2012-jan", "2012-dec", "2012-feb", "2013-may", "2013-jul", "2013-jun", "2014-jan", "2014-dec", "2014-may", "2015-may", "2015-jan", "2015-jun", "2016-jan", "2016-dec"],
    testArr1 = ["2009-February", "2009-January", "2010-March", "2010-January", "2011-July", "2011-September", "2011-January", "2012-January", "2012-December", "2012-February", "2013-May", "2013-July", "2013-June", "2014-January", "2014-December", "2014-May", "2015-May", "2015-January", "2015-June", "2016-January", "2016-December"];

testArr.sort(yearMonth);
testArr1.sort(yearMonth);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(testArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(testArr1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using or operator `||` in `}[d[1].substring(0, 3).toLowerCase()] || 0;`

Comment: that is the default value if no month is found in the object.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean sort by date then

```
testArr.sort(function(dateA, dateB) {
  return new Date(dateA) - new Date(dateB)
})
```

If you want it freshest date first flip dateA with dateB.

Run example on tonic:
https://tonicdev.com/lipp/sort-dates

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom `comparison` method and pass that to `sort` method. Here is a simple demo to do that so.

```js
var months = [ "jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"]

var testArr = ["2009-feb", "2009-jan", "2010-mar", "2010-jan", "2011-jul", "2011-sep", "2011-jan", "2012-jan", "2012-dec", "2012-feb", "2013-may", "2013-jul", "2013-jun", "2014-jan", "2014-dec", "2014-may", "2015-may", "2015-jan", "2015-jun", "2016-jan", "2016-dec"];
var testArr1 = ["2009-February", "2009-January", "2010-March", "2010-January", "2011-July", "2011-September", "2011-January", "2012-January", "2012-December", "2012-February", "2013-May", "2013-July", "2013-June", "2014-January", "2014-December", "2014-May", "2015-May", "2015-January", "2015-June", "2016-January", "2016-December"];  

var sortOrder="asc";
var compare = function(a, b) {
  var aParts = a.toLowerCase().split("-");
  var bParts = b.toLowerCase().split("-");
  
  var dateA = new Date(parseInt(aParts[0]), months.indexOf(aParts[1].substring(0, 3)));
  var dateB = new Date(parseInt(bParts[0]), months.indexOf(bParts[1].substring(0, 3)));
  
  if (sortOrder === "asc")
    return dateA - dateB;
  else
    return dateB - dateA;
}

var sortedTestArr = testArr.sort(compare);
var sortedTestArr1 = testArr1.sort(compare);


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedTestArr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(sortedTestArr1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first array, try this

```
var monthArray = ["jan","feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "june", "july", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];

testArr.sort(function(a,b){
  var ayearmonth = a.split("-");
  var byearmonth = b.split("-");
  var montha = monthArray.indexOf(ayearmonth);
  var monthb = monthArray.indexOf(byearmonth );
  if(ayearmonth[0]  != byearmonth[0] )
  {
     return ayearmonth[0] - byearmonth[0];
  }
  {
    return montha-monthb;
  }
});
```

Similar approach to be used for second array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zyc10hsv/)**

```
var sortOrder="asc";
testArr.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (sortOrder == "asc") {
        return new Date(Date.Parse(b)) - new Date(Date.Parse(a));
    }
    else {
        return new Date(Date.Parse(a)) - new Date(Date.Parse(b));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Underscore JS to sort by date

Example like :-

```
 var newConsultantData = _.sortBy(consultantData, function(o) { return o.created; });
```